# Trouble installiing Shogun on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, shogun

When I try to add the ppa to my system as

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shogun-toolbox/stable 
sudo apt-get update
```

I get the following messages:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/shogun-toolbox/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.     
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use. 
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details. 
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/shogun-toolbox/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404  Not Found 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How do I resolve these issues?

Answer (score 0):

if you check out the stable ppa repository you'll see that stable shogun packages are only available at this very moment for trusty.

if you want to use shogun on xenial (based on your logs) your current option is just to use the nightly ppa. with the new release this will change of course.